# How to use one query for two tables representing a poll with multiple answers?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables **poll** and **poll_answers**, which represent a poll and the options to choose from to answer a question from the poll. EX:

> Am I poor at SQL?
>
> - yes
> - yes, you do
> - change craft

and the co-responding tables:

**poll**

```
pollID pollQuestion

 1 | Am I poor at SQL?
```

---

**poll_answers**

```
pollAnswerID pollAnswerText pollID

  1 | yes | 1

  2 | yes, you do | 1

  3 | change craft | 1
```

---

and this is how I get the data:

```
$polls=$db->get_results("SELECT pollID, pollQuestion FROM poll",ARRAY_A);
    foreach ($polls as $poll_field)
    {
        $poll['id']=$poll_field['pollID'];
        $poll['question']=$poll_field['pollQuestion'];
        $tmp=$poll['id'];
        //answers
        $answers=$db->get_results("SELECT pollAnswerID, pollAnswerText FROM poll_answers WHERE pollID='$tmp'",ARRAY_A);
            {
            //and so on , I think you get the idea.
            }


    }
```

It looks very clumsy to me as I think that it is possible to get the data with only one SQL query using INNER JOIN on the ID match...I just couldn't do it. Can you help? Keep in mind that there are multiple polls in my database.

---

**Edit:** thank you for the answers so far. I appreciate the help. But I didn't explain the question well. Is it possible to get all the polls with all the answers in an array or object using only one `SELECT`. In the answers so far you  used the `$tmp` variable which is already taken from a previous query. So is it possible to do it or is it me not getting the answers?

Comment: I couldn't make the tables right, please someone show me how to edit them for me to look like real tables :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT pollQuestion, pollAnswerID, pollAnswerText
FROM   poll_answers pa, poll p
WHERE  p.pollID='$tmp'
       AND pa.pollId = p.pollID
```

or, if you prefer `INNER JOIN` syntax,

```
SELECT pollQuestion, pollAnswerID, pollAnswerText
FROM   poll p
INNER JOIN
       poll_answers pa
ON     pa.pollId = p.pollID
WHERE  p.pollID='$tmp'
```

To get eveything in an array, you use:

```
SELECT  -1, pollQuestion
FROM    poll p
WHERE   p.pollID = @pollID
UNION ALL
SELECT  pollAnswerID, pollAnswerText
FROM    poll_answers pa
WHERE   pa.pollID= @pollID
```

Comment: Looks like rocket science but it works. I should take a look at some advanced Sql tutorials. ty

Comment: @Quassnoi: can you please refer me to a page where these actions are explained more thoroughly (SELECT  -1 and the use of the @ sign).ty

Comment: SELECT -1 just selects a constant `-1` instead of a column. @ defines a session variable: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT polls.pollID, answers.pollAnswerID, answers.pollAnswerText 
FROM poll polls
LEFT JOIN poll_anwers answers ON polls.pollID = answers.pollID
WHERE polls.pollID = " . (int) $pollId . "
```

Answer (score 1):

You want all answers for all polls? Just remove the pollID constraint:

SELECT p.pollID p.pollQuestion, pa.pollAnswerID, pa.pollAnswerText
FROM   poll p, poll_answers pa
WHERE pa.pollID = p.pollID